# How does msfvenom shellcode actually work to execve sh -c ls

Tags: linux, assembly, x86-64, reverse-engineering, shellcode

```
MOV    RAX, 0x68732f6e69622f
CDQ
PUSH   RAX
PUSH   RSP
POP    RDI
PUSH   RDX
PUSH   0x632d
PUSH   RSP
POP    RSI
PUSH   RDX
CALL   FUN_0000001e
INSB   RDI, DX
JNC    FUN_0000001e

FUN_0000001e:
PUSH   RSI
PUSH   RDI
PUSH   RSP
POP    RSI
PUSH   0x3b
POP    RAX
SYSCALL
```

These are the assembly instructions for the `msfvenom` payload:

> ```
> msfvenom -p linux/x64/exec CMD='ls'
> ```

I understand how the `execve` systemcall is prepared, and `/bin/sh -c` passed as an argument. But how is this code executing the `ls` command ?

I tried executing this shellcode using c function pointer, and it executed `ls` as expected.

Answer (score 5):

Single-step it in a debugger and watch the values on the stack change.

`0x0068732f6e69622f` is `'/bin/sh'` with a terminating 0 byte.

`push rsp`/`pop rdi` is a 2-byte way to do `mov rdi, rsp`.

`insb` / `jnc` don't actually run, those are just data.  `insb`'s machine code is just `0x6c`; it's a "string" instruction that implicitly uses `[rdi]` post-incremented.  IDK what asm syntax this is for, but it's not NASM.  To get NASM to assemble it, I just removed the operands so it was plain `insb`.

If you assemble this and look at the machine code, you can see the bytes:

```
...
  401017:       e8 03 00 00 00          call   40101f <FUN_0000001e>
  40101c:       6c                      ins    BYTE PTR es:[rdi],dx
  40101d:       73 00                   jae    40101f <FUN_0000001e>

000000000040101f <FUN_0000001e>:
  40101f:       56                      push   rsi
 ...
```

ASCII `6C 73 00` is `"ls"` zero-terminated.  That's the string whose address was pushed by `call`.

A normal person would write that as `db 0x6c, 0x73, 0` or `db "ls", 0` instead of "disassembling" those bytes into instruction mnemonics.

---

Note that this "shellcode" is not free from `0` bytes: a forward `call` will have zeros in the high 3 bytes of the `rel32` (the "return" address that is pushed, is the address of the ASCII bytes that follow it).  Also, `push 0x632d` is a qword push of a sign-extended imm32 whose high 2 bytes are 0, since there's no `push word` size override.

And `jae` with rel8=0 of course has a zero byte.

Two ways to make this work in NUL-free shellcode involve putting the `call` + 0-terminated string at the end of the payload, so it's calling backwards.  `jmp rel8` to the `call`, then jump backward to near where you came from with the string address on the stack.  The call/pop trick is widely used in shellcode examples.  Or in x86-64 code, `lea rdi, [mystring + 0x11111111]` / `sub rdi, 0x11111111`, but that takes more bytes of machine code.

Other options include creating it from immediates like `mov eax, 'xxls'` ; `shr eax, 16` / `push rax`, or `mov eax, 'ls' ^ 0x11111111` / `xor eax, 0x11111111` / `push rax`.  (The same technique can work for the `-c` part, or you might be able to cram parts of them into one immediate.)  Or have the string bytes there in the payload with a non-zero placeholder, and `mov byte [reg+whatever], al` to store zero bytes where they need to go, from some register that you zeroed with `xor eax, eax` or whatever.  Or AH would already be zero if you materialized an 8-bit constant with `push 1` / `pop rax` (3 bytes).

msfvenom can make shellcode that voids zero bytes if you ask it to, so you can see what strategy it picks.

Comment: I upvoted. The OP is using Metasploit tools. It happens to be that msfvenom can produce payloads that are encoded or not. The OP isn't using any of the advanced options by invoking it as `msfvenom -p linux/x64/exec CMD='ls'`. msfvenom's payload generator can produce encoded output free of NULLs if desired. It looks like the OP is just trying to understand the basic output of creating an exec payload that runs `ls`.

Comment: "since there's no `push word` size override" I believe there is an `o16` push immediate instruction even in a 64-bit CS, it just happens to push a word rather than extending into a dword or qword, if I recall.

Comment: @ecm: Correct, the two possible operand-sizes for `push` in 64-bit mode are 16 and 64-bit. (*[How many bytes does the push instruction push onto the stack when I don't specify the operand size?](//stackoverflow.com/q/45127993)*).  But if you actually write `o16 push 0x1234` in NASM, that's equivalent to `push word 0x1234` `add [rax], al` (`66 68 34 12 00 00`, prepending a `66` operand-size prefix *without* adjusting the immediate to be only 16 bits instead of 32.)  The asm source doesn't use either of these.  Apparently that's expected since Michael Petch says nul-avoidance isn't the default.